# Do the glowing holes have any extra benefits after the treasure has been dug up?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Around the island you can sometimes find little cracks in the ground with a glowing aura of sorts. When you use the shovel on these spots, they seem to only reward large bags of Bells.  Afterwards, the hole leaves behind this golden glowing aura in the spot where they were, where normally it would just be a black hole.

Is there any sort of benefit to burying items within these holes? Or planting trees?   Feels like if the game made it so that there were black holes and golden holes there'd be some sort of difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can plant up to 10,000 bells in this glowing hole. When the tree matures, like any other tree, it will bear three times that amount as bell bag "fruit" (3x 10,000 bell bags).

Comment: I find myself unable to plant bells in the hole. When I approach the hole, pull out a 10k stack of bells from my pocket (into a bag), the only options I have are to "Put Away Item" which returns the bells back to my pocket, or "drop", which drops it away from the hole.

Comment: @senpai do you have your shovel equipped? Can’t bury bells or fruit etc. without it

Comment: Just to confirm this: today, after I dug out a glowing hole, I equipped a shovel, put 10,000 bells in my inventory, and while standing next to the hole, selected the 10,000 bells and picked "Bury in hole". A little sapling appeared in its place immediately. I don't know if you have to water it, but I did anyway.

Comment: @IvoCoumans nope no need to water trees, just flowers

Comment: @Wolf Are you sure the limit is only 10k bells?

Comment: @senpai I have yet to test more but the guides say it’s the limit

Answer (score 3):

This glowing hole is able to grow a money tree. Put some Bells in this hole and a tree will grow, taking as much time as other trees, and within the same period a fruit tree will be able to give fruits, this tree will give Bells.

Comment: It's not clear to me if this is from experience with new horizons, of if you've posted an answer that is relevant to the gamecube version with the assumption it hasn't changed.  Could you clarify that?  Answering a question about new horizons with info from the gamecube version that may be different now could be misleading.

Comment: @Tal Thanks for your feedback. I tried to clarify my answer. Since the game is still pretty new, I kept the part on the Gamecube version, clarifying it has not been tested yet on New Horizons (and with hope someone will be able to test it). If it is still too confusing or misleading I can still remove it.

Comment: Unfortunately, as is, this answer doesn't actually answer the question - it is part speculation and part irrelevant (because it's for the previous game).  It is likely it will continue to acquire downvotes until it is either removed or updated to have relevant information for the question that was asked.

Comment: Thanks. So I updated to keep only what is needed.

Comment: Now that the question has been edited, it definitely does not deserve the downvotes it has, since the latest game does indeed have this feature. There are a plethora of online sources confirming this, here are just a few - https://www.polygon.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-switch-acnh-guide/2020/3/20/21183443/money-trees-bells-plant-grow https://www.ign.com/wikis/animal-crossing-new-horizons/How_to_Plant_a_Money_Tree https://www.gamesradar.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-money-tree/

Comment: The limit on each bell "fruit" is 10,000 bells. Planting more than 10,000 has no benefit.